# Apache site redirect configuration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, virtualhost

This is my situation:

- Client bought a domain for their site, www.site.com!
- I configured a new site inside /var/www/hosts/www.site.com.war folder.
- Client requested of me to configure Apache server (Live server) to do the following:

  - Allow access to the created site if "live.site.com" URL is requested, plus password protection. This is standard "before go live" procedure, and it requires of invited clients to configure their hosts file ("Live_server_IP" and "live.site.com").
  - Redirect to the other domain page "www.othersite.com/page.jsp" if "www.site.com" URL is requested.

This is my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/www.site.com.war/

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/png A2592000

    JkMount /*.jsp xyz
    JkMount /*.xml xyz

    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.site.com

    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$www.site.com(.*)& http://www.othersite.com/page.jsp [R=301]

    # Remove this password protection after go-live
    <Directory /var/www/hosts/www.site.com.war/ >
          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "By Invitation Only"
          AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/site.htpasswd

          require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


# For internal company use
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName live.site.com

    ProxyPass / http://www.site.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.site.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration only provides a password protected access to the new site for both URL requests, "www.site.com" and "live.site.com", which is not what I need to do.

I also tried using different RewriteRule-s: "www.site.com", ".*", "^/(.*)&", using L flag, etc.; omitting RewriteCond etc.

I was wondering, is it possible to configure Apache server as my client requested? If it is, what I am doing wrong in Apache  configurations?

Thank you.

Comment: two different sites can share the same document root. there's no need for the proxying and whatnot, just have the `live` version share the same document root.

Comment: No, that does not work. Because when I add DocumentRoot to the live version redirection works as it should but I get '404 Page Error' when accessing live URL Index.jsp. It is because all of the JBoss configurations contain www.site.com value, or at least I think that that is the reason.